# What's the smart way to handle hundreds of images on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system

I have a simple webpage with hundreds of images.
Like this...

```
<img src="img/photo00001.jpg">
<img src="img/photo00002.jpg">
<img src="img/photo00003.jpg">
... and so on
```

I don't want to spend hours copy pasting and editing the numbers to later realize I forgot the anchor tag on them. I know Wordpress would do it but this is supposed to be a **simple project** and all layout and design is already done, theming it would be a complete overkill.

What's the smart approach to this?

- custom auto built CMS? *I've heard about it but don't know much*
- Sublime plugin that generates the HTML? *don't think it writes the img path*
- Some other idea?

Mind you I'm a front end guy.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but your question doesn't make sense?

Comment: Sublime? CMS? Why not just `document.getElementById("containerId").appendChild(...)` inside a plain JavaScript `for` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really ugly, but i think it will do what you want :

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function addZero(number){
 var zeros;
 switch(number.toString().length) {
    case 1:
        zeros= "0000";
        break;
    case 2:
        zeros= "000";
        break;
    case 3:
        zeros= "00";
        break;
    case 4:
        zeros= "0";
        break;
 }

 return zeros;
}

for(var i=0;i<1030; i++){
 $("body").append("<img src='img/photo"+ addZero(i) + i +".jpg'/>");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy/Paste this into a .html file and run it, then copy the source code of the generated page...

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks Leo. Adding the zeros was clever.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but I have done similar things in the past using php (don't get scared!).

```
<body>
 <div class="img-container>
  <?php
  define('N_IMAGES', 20);
  $class = 'image';
  for ($i=0;$i<N_IMAGES;$i++) {
    echo "<img src = \"img/photo"+$i+"\" class=\"$class\">";
  }
?>
</div>
</body>
```

Breakdown:

1. You use a constant N_IMAGES according to the number of images you have.
2. Use a for to cycle an "echo" statement. What this does is return an
   image tag with each image route.
3. You can associate a class to each image, as well as any attributes
   you may need.

Be wary. You will need a local or remote server for php to work, as well as saving as .php, not html.

It's a fast, clean way to do it if you don't mind throwing in some basic php.

Comment: Thanks JF That's the best solution I guess but I chose to run with the javascript solution as it doesn't need a server and it's in a language I already understand. Voted it up though. The breakdown was really kind.